# C++ vector::push_back C1001 Internal compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I am playing a little bit with C++ and SDL2 on Visual Studio 2013.
All worked fine until this line of code:

```
Obstacle o = Obstacle(Vector2f(SCENE_WIDTH, 0), Vector2f(1, 1));
**obstacles1->push_back(o);**
```

If I comment out the push_back line all work fine.
Now come the crazy thing.
If I remove all **virtual** modifiers from the Obstacle class the push_back function works and the error is not thrown.

With this the error is thrown:

```
class Obstacle : public Rectangle
{
public:
    Obstacle(const Vector2f& position, const Vector2f& size);
    Obstacle();
    virtual ~Obstacle();
public:
    virtual void update(float dt);
    virtual void render() const;
};
```

And with this it works fine:

```
class Obstacle : public Rectangle
{
public:
    Obstacle(const Vector2f& position, const Vector2f& size);
    Obstacle();
    ~Obstacle();
public:
    void update(float dt);
    void render() const;
};
```

How to fix it, so I can make my obstacle have virtual functions ?

EDIT:
If I make a function or destructor virtual in the Rectangle class I get the error, too.

Comment: Could you give a minimal but complete and compilable example that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @user4581301 the title says it all: "C1001 Internal compiler error"

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant so it does, Brain read right over that.

Comment: What is the data type of your vector (obstacles1)?